# How to run .js file from a command line on windows?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have a shortcut with 'target' `"C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\taf.js"`.

I want to run that from a batch file so I copied the `"C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\taf.js"` into cmd.exe command line and pressed enter. Nothing happened.

How can I run `"C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\taf.js"` from a command line on Windows7?

### update

the js file contains

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
WshShell.run("java -Dlog.dir=%TEMP% -jar taf-loader.jar", 0, false);
WScript.exit;
```

I tried to run the js file with both `Wscript.exe` and `Cscript.exe` as @Serge suggested but nothing worked = the program I start by doubleclicking hasn't started. No error either.

```
C:\>Cscript.exe "C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\taf.js"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\>Wscript.exe "C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\taf.js"

C:\>
```

Comment: What language is the .js file written in JavaScript or JScript?

Comment: @Robert: I don't know. It's not my script. It's a commercial product that I want to be able to start by one click or in a very fast way (Windows7). If I pin what is running it won't start next time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have two options:

```
Cscript.exe "C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\taf.js"
```

or

```
Wscript.exe "C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\taf.js"
```

The former one starts the command line version of Windows Scripting Host and the latter one is starting the window version.

The command line options are documented here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cscript

and here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wscript

In your script file you should use the full path to your jar file and possibly full path to the java.exe

Alternatively, to allow the `java.exe` locate the `tar-loader.jar` file you should change the current directory to the one containing this file, so before invoking `wscript` make `cd "C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\"`

As you mentioned that you like to run this script in a single touch, you also may create a shortcut on your desktop that has a command line set to `Wscript.exe "C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\taf.js"` and working directory set to `C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\`

Comment: I agree with Serge, why not run `java -Dlog.dir=%TEMP% -jar taf-loader.jar` from the command-line or batch directly? Why this round-about method? (Obviously, java.exe has to be in the PATH.)

Comment: @Karan & Serge: See my comment under my question. It is not my script.  I don't want to modify it. Maybe I can use code from it to create my own batch file or something like that. I prefer not to modify anything.

Comment: "Maybe I can use code from it to create my own batch file or something like that." - Yeah, so what happens when you do?

Comment: It was just a though. I don't know how to do it right now and I am not  sure if can cause any troubles why I start the program in such batch and it is not 100% correct.

Comment: @Radek does both tar-loader.jar reside in the same 'C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\' directory?

Comment: Did you mean `taf-loder.jar` and `taf.js`? Yes there are in the same folder `C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\`

Comment: @Radek please see the update to the answer

Comment: If I run `Wscript.exe "C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\taf.js"` from `C:\Users\Public\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\` it works! thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you can run 'java' in a console window with no errors, then

1) Create a text file on your desktop called 'taf.txt'

2) Enter "java -Dlog.dir=%TEMP% -jar taf-loader.jar" into the text file, and save it

3) Rename the file to 'taf.bat'

Done.

Using a scripting host to start a script which launches a shell that launches a java program is just too long winded.

Think of it in terms of what you want to achieve - you want the program to launch with a click of an icon.

The batch file is the fastest way to achieve that on win7.

If you were using an OS that could natively kick off a Javascript script with no messing about it would be a nice way to launch it, but that script wouldn't work on anything other than windows (unless ActiveX is ported now - been a long time since I've used it).

Source: Professional Java Developer for over 10 years

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.6 comes with `jrunscript` to run JavaScript outside of web browsers.

Comment: It's not for javascript (js) files: it's for Java scripts and (now) not included in JRE.